# Dividing up columns and submitting the value as stdin into a seperate program within a script

Tags: shell, shell-script

I currently have two programs written in C named "remove" and "calculate".

When I call ./remove it removes some data from stdin.
When I call ./calculate which takes in an argument and also data from stdin and calculates and returns a value.

Currently writing a script that calls both of these programs.

I call my script with the following:

```
./calc.sh input.txt 2 3 4 5
```

where input.txt has:

```
abcd:1,2:3,4
efgh:5,4:4,4
hijk:3,1:4,9
```

Running the ./remove program returns

```
abcd:1,2:3,4
efgh:5,4:4,4
```

My script is currently:

```
./remove "$1" | ./calculate "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" < awk -F ':,' '
```

How do I fix the script so that I select the values from the columns of integers returned from the ./remove program and submit it line by line into ./calculate as stdin along with "2 3 4 5" with arguments?

Comment: `remove` removes *what* data from stdin? ... why? `calculate` takes what as an argument? ... why? `calculate` calculates what? ... why? How does `calculate`'s argument relate to the data it reads from stdin? ... why?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your objective correctly, you are somewhat close. 
Try

```
#!/bin/sh
filename=$1
shift
./remove "$filename" | awk -F '[:,]' '{print $2, $3, $4, $5}' | ./calculate "$@"
```

You need to say `-F '[:,]'`
because each field separator is *either* a `:` or `,`. 
`awk -F ':,'` expects the field separator to be the string `:,`, as in

```
field1:,field2:,field3
```

The `shift` command removes `$1` (which is the filename, `input.txt`)
from the list of arguments, leaving `"$@"` to expand as `2`, `3`, `4`, and `5`.

Comment: This doesn't account for the values returned from the ./remove program ie. "5,4:4,4" as stdin and "$2, $3, $4, $5" as argument values

Comment: What are you talking about? Have you tried it? What happens?

Comment: it returns the errors
filename: command not found and awk: cannot open [:,] (no such file directory)

Comment: I hate to ask, but are you sure you used what I gave you?  Exactly?  If you said `filename = $1` (with spaces), that would result in a "filename: command not found" error.  And I can't imagine how you could have gotten an error message that said `[:,"` if you typed `[:,]`.  But saying `-f` instead of `-F` could explain the " awk: cannot open ... (no such file directory)" error.

Comment: it seems changing to filename=$1 has fixed all the errors but now it just waits for an input and when I try typing anything nothing occurs

Comment: OK, are you sure that `./remove input.txt` produces the output you expect?  If so, try running `./remove input.txt | awk -F '[:,]' '{print $2, $3, $4, $5}'` and check what that does.

Comment: Output was almost producing what is expected except it was leaving out the last value so I just shifted the arguments by one and it seems to output all the proper values however when I run the script it still sits waiting for some sort of input and never terminates.

Comment: Let me get this straight: `./remove input.txt | awk -F '[:,]' '{print $2, $3, $4, $5}'` runs and terminates, but `./remove input.txt | awk -F '[:,]' '{print $2, $3, $4, $5}' | ./calculate 2 3 4 5` sits waiting for some sort of input and never terminates?  That just doesn't make any sense.  What does `./calculate 2 3 4 5 < /dev/null` do?

Comment: I seem to have messed up somewhere but I fixed it up abit.
 `'./remove < "$1" | awk -F '[:,]' '{print $2, $3, $4, $5}'` returns `1234, 5444` .
`./remove < "$1" | awk -F '[:,]' '{print $2, $3, $4, $5}' | ./calculate 2 3 4 5`
returns some odd values in the high thousands when it should be two digits

Comment: Upvoted for a valiant effort, but this to-ing and fro-ing is symptomatic of a poorly constructed question...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
./remove $1 |  awk -F '[:,]' '{ printf "./calculate %d %d %d %d\n",$2,$3,$4,$5 }' | bash
```

where

- `awk` will generate command line to stdout
- and give it to `bash` (or any shell )

you can test by simply running

```
./remove $1 |  awk -F '[:,]' '{ printf "./calculate %d %d %d %d\n",$2,$3,$4,$5 }'
```

However,

> When I call ./calculate which takes in an argument and also data from stdin and calculates and returns a value.

can you explain what input must be given to `./calculate` ? In the construction above, I assume calculate use no input.